# Accumulate score in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, accumulator

```
The situation is this:
```

```
    1/ Class Grid.as 

    - Obtain the value of the option chosen // score:Number 

    - Generate a new instance: generateTrivia  // trivia:generateTrivia 

    - Send the score value using a method // trivia.sendScore(score) 


    2/ Class generateTriva 

     - Save the score value score   


      private function sendScore(rScore:Number){
         this.pt = rScore;
      }


    - I created a variable to update the score after the question is answered  
     //  private var finalScore:Number = 0;

    - When the user clicks on send button: 

    a. Validate the answer 
 
    b. update the finalScore

     //  finalScore = finalScore + this.pt;

    - Finally I update the textfield to show the score 


    Note:

    I've observed that the first time when the user answer the question correctly the
    accumulator: finalScore works fine but after that I don't know why does not add the new
    value of the variable (this.pt ) to the stored result


    UPDATED: I found something. After the answer is validated, the instance is removed and back to grilla, then repeat the process by question. I should store the result of the validation and send it back to the grid class and then process accumulate the  value
```

Comment: It looks like pu is 0 until set in recibirPuntaje(). Is recibirPuntaje() ever called? More generally, what is happening?

Comment: Where do you call: `score = score + pu;`? In the constructor?

Comment: @sch: score is called inside of the conditional sentence in order to processs the information: if (value == 1) {       
  score = score + pu;
    
(parent.getChildByName("barra") as MovieClip).puntajeTXT.text = String(score);
   }

Comment: @jhocking:  recibirPuntaje() is a private function and it used to receive the value from the other class where I've saved the score of each option

Comment: how is initializeTrival talking to generateTrivia? and is generateTrivia doing score=score+pu; or another class?

Comment: initializeTrivia is the instance of the class generateTrivia and this class applies that

Comment: Nobody knows how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear and include some relevant code? This can help us see what is happening there.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to debug a program. An error can be something started from uninitialized variable to "1 " (see the space there) converted to NaN.

The simplest way is to add `trace()` statements in the functions where your `score` and `pu` values change. Better way is to set a breakpoint when user selects an option to answer and step through the execution monitoring variables.

Comment: I'm debugging the app since the mid-day, I traced all the class and nothing, now I'm following the flow to identify where is the problem because the first time when the user answer correctly the question score added 100 but the second time the variable keeps the same value and not add the new value to the accumulator score

Comment: I found that when I choose an option with a value ( e.g  300 ) the application updates the text but after that I select another option, the accumulator variable didn't work.. basically replaced the old value with a new one ( e.g 100 )